# Time Zone Offset Calculations

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Let's suppose the server gives the date in this format:

```
 var date = '2012-08-08T15:04:33+0200';
```

As you can see the previous date has a Timezone offset of two hours.

Let's suppose I need to display the same date in different places having different timezone.

What is the proper way to display the date in different clients having the different time zone using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

I did try the following but I am not sure because I cannot test it.

```
  moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation it should be enough just passing the following parameter ´Z´ or `ZZ` according your date format.

So in your case it should be:

```
var date = '2012-08-08T15:04:33+0200';
moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ").fromNow();
```